# How do I navigate between pages on NextJS using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, radio-group

I'm working on a NextJS project and have a side bar for user navigation. I'm using a radio group because when someone clicks on one of the options, the radio button will light up and remain lit up until a different button is clicked and directs the user to another page.

```
              <Link href="/">
                <input
                  name="connected"
                  id="home"
                  type="radio"
                  className="peer/home "
                  value="first"
                  onChange={(e) => setDone(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label
                  for="home"
                  className="bg-red-500 peer-checked/home:bg-blue-500"
                >
                  CLick me
                </label>
              </Link>
              <br></br>
              <Link href="/trucks">
                <input
                  name="connected"
                  id="no"
                  type="radio"
                  className="peer/no"
                  value="second"
                  onChange={(e) => setDone(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label
                  for="no"
                  className="bg-red-500 peer-checked/no:bg-blue-500"
                >
                  CLick here
                </label>
              </Link>
```

Here is the general layout for how I have it structed. When the user clicks on one of the options the label will change colors and will remain like that until the user clicks a different button. When I try and click one the radio buttons, the link will work but the button/label doesn't change colors.
If anyone has any better/efficient ideas please share. Still learning NextJS

Comment: Use `router.push` inside the `input`s `onChange` callback instead for the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into integrating state in your project:

https://nextjs.org/learn/foundations/from-javascript-to-react/adding-interactivity-with-state

With state, in your setDone method you can update the state for that particular element.

In this case, we can use `setElementMode(0, true)` to set the element to active.

For example:

```
const [elements, setElements] = React.useState();

const setElementMode = (element_id, mode) => {
    let elements_clone = [...elements];
    elements_clone.map(element => {
        if (element.id === element_id) {
            element.mode = mode;
        }
    });

    setElements(elements_clone);
}
```

The only thing you will need to do before this code works well, is load the elements state with the data containing all of your elements.